# How to optimize perspective continuous moving vertical background in Flash As3?

Tags: actionscript-3

Background should run continuously moving in vertically respective to perspective direction. My problem is background is not smooth in android devices and also pix-elating. I am using Papervision 3d for background running process. And most importantly i have attained my perspective view for my project but not smoothness.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Papervision is pretty old. You will get better performance with Away3d  http://away3d.com/

Comment: But I have done my current project in Papervision3d so could you tell me is there any better way to improve the performance

Comment: I can't – haven't used it for years. You understand that Papervision was discontinued in 2009? Also that it uses software rendering only while Away3D and Flare3d both use hardware acceleration. Assuming you will do more projects in the future, it is worth looking into a modern codebase rather than trying to get an old/dead codebase to do what it may not be able to do.

Comment: Thanks for your words. My current project was 2d track racer game, please tell me how to do the moving backing continuously in perspective view. As I am new to this level of game, kindly assist me.

Comment: Thanks for your words. Please tell me the how to develop the code for the background running continuously in perspective view.As I am begginer to these level of game. Kindly assist me and also give some tutorials.